# Regular Expression to capture text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq

I have a log file with content like this:

> ```
> 2012-07-16 03:20:41,23796160897,Text,id:SAR-23796160897-c0-2-1 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120715220216 done date:120716032038 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FOTSO TOKAM,SMSCReceiptMsgId=SAR-23796160897-c0-2-1
> 2012-07-16 03:20:48,23796160897,Text,id:SAR-23796160897-c0-2-2 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120715220216 done date:120716032045 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FOTSO TOKAM,SMSCReceiptMsgId=SAR-23796160897-c0-2-2
> 2012-05-04 00:07:46,23777603300,Text,id:4FA23EB0 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225018 done date:120504000744 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23EB0
> 2012-05-04 01:50:18,23796726987,Text,id:4FA23E95 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225014 done date:120504015016 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23E95
> 2012-05-04 01:50:22,23799757015,Text,id:4FA23EB2 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225018 done date:120504015021 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23EB2
> 2012-05-04 01:50:48,23799907239,Text,id:4FA23F38 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225042 done date:120504015046 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23F38
> 2012-05-04 01:50:48,23799896455,Text,id:4FA23D1C sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503175232 done date:120504015046 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23D1C
> 2012-05-04 01:50:48,23799896455,Text,id:4FA23F04 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225031 done date:120504015046 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23F04
> 2012-05-04 01:50:50,23794105044,Text,id:4FA23F55 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225046 done date:120504015048 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23F55
> 2012-05-04 01:51:19,23796029764,Text,id:4FA23FEE sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225114 done date:120504015117 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23FEE
> 2012-05-04 02:17:51,23775461594,Text,id:4FA24025 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225125 done date:120504021749 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA24025
> 2012-05-04 04:08:02,23777437781,Text,id:4FA23F23 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120503225037 done date:120504040800 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23F23
> 2012-05-04 04:50:12,23777970013,Text,id:4FA23E70 sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225005 done date:120504045011 stat:EXPIRED err:027 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23E70
> 2012-05-04 04:50:15,23775182832,Text,id:4FA23E7E sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225008 done date:120504045014 stat:EXPIRED err:027 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23E7E
> 2012-05-04 04:50:17,23777789644,Text,id:4FA23E80 sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225010 done date:120504045016 stat:EXPIRED err:027 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23E80
> 2012-05-04 04:50:21,23777529371,Text,id:4FA23E8F sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225013 done date:120504045019 stat:EXPIRED err:027 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23E8F
> 2012-05-04 04:50:21,23777613852,Text,id:4FA23E97 sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225014 done date:120504045020 stat:EXPIRED err:027 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23E97
> 2012-05-04 04:50:24,23777407598,Text,id:4FA23EAE sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225017 done date:120504045023 stat:EXPIRED err:032 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23EAE
> 2012-05-04 04:50:26,23777736950,Text,id:4FA23EAF sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225018 done date:120504045024 stat:EXPIRED err:027 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23EAF
> 2012-05-04 04:50:31,23775834128,Text,id:4FA23ED6 sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225024 done date:120504045030 stat:EXPIRED err:027 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23ED6
> 2012-05-04 04:50:36,23777486441,Text,id:4FA23EF3 sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:120503225029 done date:120504045035 stat:EXPIRED err:027 text:,FLP,SMSCReceiptMsgId=4FA23EF3
> ```

Now I want to capture the value from this content for few specific fields like "id,done date,stat" by using regular expression with c#.net and LINQ.

Please help me if any one have any idea to do it.

Comment: Any particular language you want to use?

Comment: Which regex engine are you going to use?

Comment: yes Keppil by using C#.net and Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a csv parser would be better but you can use this regex and replace the id: with the other fields you wanted. ex `done date:(?<done date>.*?)\s`

```
string strRegex = @"id:(?<id>.*?)\s.*?done date:(?<donedate>.*?)\s.*?stat:(?<stat>.*?)\s";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"2012-07-16 03:20:41,23796160897,Text,id:SAR-23796160897-c0-2-1 sub:000 dlvrd:001 submit date:120715220216 done date:120716032038 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:,FOTSO TOKAM,SMSCReceiptMsgId=SAR-23796160897-c0-2-1"
foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here 
    //myMatch.Groups["id"].Value;
    //myMatch.Groups["donedate"].Value;
    //myMatch.Groups["stat"].Value;
  }
}
```

You can use one regex `id:(?<id>.*?)\s.*?done date:(?<donedate>.*?)\s.*?stat:(?<stat>.*?)\s` then access with groups like `myMatch.Groups["id"].Value`

Comment: Is it possible to read all specific field like "id,done date,stat" together ?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you Regex will help you here a lot. Rather you should split the lines into rows and then into columns as I can see the data can be segmented into a matrix from where you can easily extract information that you are looking for... even you can do this in JavaScript/C#/Java or any language.

In my practice do this this:

- split the data into lines
- split the line into columns
- then iterate through each line and point to the column that you are looking for.

  ```
  var content = data.split('\n');
  foreach(var line in content) 
  {
       var cols = line.split(',');
       var c1 = cols[0];
       var c2 = cols[1];
       var c3 = cols[2];
  }
  ```

You can refine the above excerpt to fit your need... That is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what all of your fields mean, or if the separator characters are constant.  With the test data you provided, this gets most of the information into named groups.

```
/// <summary>
///  Regular expression built for C# on: Tue, Jul 17, 2012, 12:08:12 PM
///  Using Expresso Version: 3.0.4334, http://www.ultrapico.com
///  
///  A description of the regular expression:
///  
///  Beginning of line or string
///  [Date]: A named capture group. [[^,]+]
///      Any character that is NOT in this class: [,], one or more repetitions
///  ,
///  [Number]: A named capture group. [[^,]+]
///      Any character that is NOT in this class: [,], one or more repetitions
///  ,
///  [Text1]: A named capture group. [[^,]+]
///      Any character that is NOT in this class: [,], one or more repetitions
///  ,
///  id:
///      id:
///  [ID]: A named capture group. [[^\s]+]
///      Any character that is NOT in this class: [\s], one or more repetitions
///  Whitespace
///  sub:
///      sub:
///  [Sub]: A named capture group. [\w+]
///      Alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
///  Whitespace
///  dlvrd:
///      dlvrd:
///  [Dlvrd]: A named capture group. [\w+]
///      Alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
///  Whitespace
///  submit\sdate:
///      submit
///      Whitespace
///      date:
///  [SubmitDate]: A named capture group. [\w+]
///      Alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
///  Whitespace
///  done\sdate:
///      done
///      Whitespace
///      date:
///  [DoneDate]: A named capture group. [\w+]
///      Alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
///  Whitespace
///  stat:
///      stat:
///  [Status]: A named capture group. [\w+]
///      Alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
///  Whitespace
///  err:
///      err:
///  [Error]: A named capture group. [\d+]
///      Any digit, one or more repetitions
///  Whitespace
///  
///
/// </summary>
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
      "^(?<Date>[^,]+),\r\n(?<Number>[^,]+),\r\n(?<Text1>[^,]+),\r\nid:(?"+
      "<ID>[^\\s]+)\\s\r\nsub:(?<Sub>\\w+)\\s\r\ndlvrd:(?<Dlvrd>\\w+)\\s"+
      "\r\nsubmit\\sdate:(?<SubmitDate>\\w+)\\s\r\ndone\\sdate:(?<DoneD"+
      "ate>\\w+)\\s\r\nstat:(?<Status>\\w+)\\s\r\nerr:(?<Error>\\d+)\\s",
    RegexOptions.Multiline
    | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
```

So with this, you can call:

```
var matches = regex.Matches(inputData);
```

I'd personally recommend that you limit the test to a single line of data and call this instead:

```
var match = regex.Match(inputLineOfData);
```

This means you can then:

```
if ( match.Success )
{
   var id = match.Groups["ID"].Value;
   var submitDate = match.Groups["SubmitDate"].Value;  // Parse to DateTime
   var doneDate = match.Groups["DoneDate"].Value;  // Parse to DateTime

   // etc for 'sub', 'dlvrd', 'Status', 'Error'..
}
```